# Is it possible to control MongoId generation?

Tags: php, mongodb

Here is the scenario. I am storing entries in MongoDB and using the _id as a public identifier for each entry when fetching them to display. Since the _id is fairly hard to guess and therefore a user with access to one entry based on the _id in the url can not guess the next or previous entry (except for the example below) based on their information. I also do not have to create extra indexes on another field containing an md5 hash or uniqid for example.

**The problem:** When creating multiple entries as part of an import job, entries get very similar _id´s due to the fact that they are partly based on timestamp. 
Three entries created during an import can look like this as an example.
52014b1a3c9fb7733d000000
52014b1a3c9fb7733d000001
52014b1a3c9fb7733d000002

In this scenario, a user might see the pattern and try to edit the last part of each identifier, and succeed in viewing another entry in this case.

**My question(s):**
Is it possible to control the MongoId generation upon document creation so that it does not use only the increment function at the end when creating large amount if entries as an import for example? Changing the device part of the id? Can that be done?

My last resort is to stop using the _id as the public identifier for the entries, forcing me to set up additional indexes on a very large collection. I hope I do not have to go there.

I am using MongoDb in a PHP based application.

Comment: Why not just implement some access control on viewing the documents?

Comment: @Phil That would require aditional indexes and that is what I want to avoid. The document has to be public for those who has recieved the corrent url.

Comment: How is this a -1 question btw? Irrelevant? Badly formulated? Duplicate? I am confused. Hope someone has a relevant answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how additional indexes would be required for some basic access control. If a user, or even an array of permitted users, was stored in the document, querying by a document ID and some other criteria would still allow MongoDB to very quickly consult the `_id` index to fetch the document, at which point other, non-indexed criteria would be evaluated. Alternatively, you could just fetch documents by `_id` and check access rights in your application (e.g. if you depend on some external ACL service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the automatic ID generation as it's a set algorithm that all drivers have to use. You can however create your own idea yourself, but you will have to do that for each document:

```
<?php
$document = array(
    "_id" => new MongoID("ffb234234....");
);
```

You just need to make sure that you pass the 24 hex chars to the constructor of `MongoID` as that format is set. However, if you do this, please make sure that you do include the PID and hash(hostname) so that you can guarantee uniqueness among more than one machine and process.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up adding an md5 hash and using that as the public identifier and adding an index for that value in the collection to speed things up.